# How to move launcher bar to the bottom in 18.10

Tags: xfce, 18.10

According to all the answers I've read, I just need to open a 'settings' menu in the top right-hand corner of my screen, but there isn't one in 18.10. (see screenshot) Where is this menu that I can change bar position to the bottom please?
[image: Ubuntu screen shot]

Comment: You use the tag "unity" suggesting that you are using the Unity desktop. Howver, the screenshot lets me expect you may be using the XFCE desktop (Xubuntu) instead. You can tell your desktop from the terminal command `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP". Then edit your post and tell what desktop you are using. Also clearly mention what you mean by "launcher bar". I only see a top bar on your screenshot.

Comment: I'm using the default that ships with 18.10. Yes it's XFCE. Do you know the solution?